# jenkins build execution is taking too much time for a selenium job

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I was learning jenkins integration with selenium scripts.So I have created a job and executing the build, in the console output I am able to see all the statements which are I am printing and the test was completed also but Progress bar is showing as EXECUTING THE BUILD.

[image: Refer the image marked location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use `quit()` instead of `close()`, because of that it is happening.

Comment: Did you find out how this difference of using functions was impacting the run? It would be good if you add more description around this.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic items I can recommend checking:

- Make sure selenium service is running.
- If you are using selenium as a OS service, then browsers are also opened in background - perhaps they're running but not visible?
- If you want to visually debug selenium, then run selenium from terminal as a logged in user.
- To make sure selenium server is running you can check URL:
  http://hostname:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getLogMessages